# Adding CSS styles to everything but a focused textarea

Tags: css, focus, textarea, pseudo-element

Only CSS please!

Basically I want to apply some styles to everything on the page (or almost everything) except for a certain textarea when that certain textarea is `:focus`ed.

So, when I focus on the textarea, everything else gets an `opacity: 0` or something like that.

I tried fiddling with `:not()` but I couldn't get it on quite work.

I also might want to expand this to say: *apply some styles to everything on the page (or almost everything) except for a certain **div** when a certain textarea is `:focus`ed.*

This is kinda an overcomplicated example I was trying to learn from:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/09/filter-functionality-with-css3/

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to ascend the DOM hierarchy using CSS, so what you'd want to do is make sure that the relevant textarea is a sibling of the container for anything that you want to have fade out.  At that point you should be able to do something like:

```
textarea:focus ~ section.toFade {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

It's an ugly fragile solution (bound by the limitations of CSS), so hopefully this is just an academic exercise.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I could figure was:

```
*:not(textarea) {
color:red !important;
}
```

As `*:not(textarea:focus)` seems to break it.